# How to use the right mouse button to drag the map in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using the leaflet.js to create a map, however, I need to use my right mouse button to drag the map, but there isn't any API in leaflet for developers to change the default option. Is there any plugin or anything else can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet only handles drag operations with the left (primary) mouse/pointer button.

The [code responsible for that is in `src/dom/Draggable.js`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/188362098b715998b60f9f90500290da81565492/src/dom/Draggable.js#L89):

```
if (L.Draggable._dragging || e.shiftKey || ((e.which !== 1) && (e.button !== 1) && !e.touches)) { return; }
```

You might want to fork the Leaflet code, modify this to suit your needs (and make sure about cross-browser compliance!!), then make a custom build. There are instructions on how to do so in the [project's documentation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Please note that the `L.Draggable` code affects dragging the map but also draggable markers.

Comment: thank you very much, i read the leaflet.js and find there is a line of codes :this._moved = !1, !(t.shiftKey || 1 !== t.which && 1 !== t.button, so i change the code, and it make sense, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events), [dragstart](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-dragstart), [drag](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-drag) events gives you the type of event that triggered drag which is contextmenu in your case.

You need to write event handlers for these events yourself to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: thank you very much, it is the first time that i ask question in stackoverflow, it helps me a lot!